# Pre select a <s:radio> button in struts 2

Tags: html, jsp, struts2

This is my radio button code.

```
<s:radio name="filter" requiredposition="right"
list="#{'STATUS_FILTER_START':'START','STATUS_FILTER_END':'STOP'}" 
 value = "STATUS_FILTER_START"></s:radio>
```

or

```
<s:radio name="filter" requiredposition="right"
list="#{'STATUS_FILTER_START':'START','STATUS_FILTER_END':'STOP'}" 
 listValue = "STATUS_FILTER_START" listKey =  "STATUS_FILTER_START"s></s:radio>
```

But nothing works.
 
Can somebody help me with this?
I dont want html:radio tag.

Comment: just set the value in your action class and use that value in `value` parameter.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110558/preselect-radio-button-in-struts2

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Hi Umesh its not working, I have initialize filter to "START" but still it is not preselected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set default value in your action class and use that in the OGNL to tell which value to select as default

```
List<String> filter= new ArrayList<String>();
        filter.add("START");
        filter.add("STOP");


    public List<String> getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }
    public String getDefaultFilterValue(){
        return "STOP";
    }
```

in your jsp use like

```
<s:radio label="filter" name="filter" list="filter" value="defaultGenderValue" />
```

i have used simple ArrayList but you are free to use Map.

Comment: Thanks umesh u always help me:)

Answer (score 3):

Also for devs who are using static values. Here's the solution:

```
<s:radio label="correctOption" name="correctAnswer" list=" 
#{'1':'1','2':'2','3':'3','4':'4'}" value="1"/>
```

another one in case of strings in a static list:

```
<s:radio label="Gender" name="gender" list=" 
    #{'male':'Male','female':'Female'}" value="'male'"/>
```